# restart activity in android

Tags: android, listview, onresume

I have one activity A, that has one button and one list view which shows names of books . on click of the button,  activity B starts, there user fill the  book form and save it . when he press back button , user comes to activity A.  Here the book name should be updated in listview. I think I have to write some code in onResume() . Can u please tell me what to  write. I am using customised list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start activity B with `startActivityForResult()` and use method `onActivityResult()` to restart or process the new data

For example, to start Activity B:

```
String callingActivity = context.getLocalClassName();
Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
newActivity.setData(Uri.parse(callingActivity));
startActivityForResult(newActivity, 0);
```

Then somewhere in your Activity A class:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == 0){
            // do processing here
        }
    }
```

The other answers should suffice, but onResume() can be called in cases where the activity is resumed by other means.

To simply restart Activity A when user presses back button from Activity B, then put the following inside the onActivityResult:

```
if(requestCode == 0){
            finish();
            startActivity(starterintent);

        }
```

And in the onCreate of Activity A, add `starterintent = getIntent();`

Just remember to initiate the variable with `Intent starterintent;` somewhere before your onCreate is called.

e.g.

```
public class ActivityA extends ListActivity {
  Intent starterintent;

  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    starterintent = getIntent();
  }

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 0){
      finish();
      startActivity(starterintent);
    }
  }

  private void startActivityB(){
    String callingActivity = context.getLocalClassName();
    Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
    newActivity.setData(Uri.parse(callingActivity));
    startActivityForResult(newActivity, 0);
  }

}
```

Then just call `startActivityB()` from a button click or whatever

Comment: Do I need to send the data from  activity B. If I need to send , how to send data .

Comment: @prabhuM that depends on how your data is stored.  If it's saved to a database, or to file, or even to sharedpreferences, then no, Activity A will be able to access it provided the user actually saves the data in Activity B before pressing back.  I don't know of a way to pass data through the back button action, though, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

YES you are right. Write code in onResume.

When you updated date just call **notifyDataSetChanged()**; for your ListView adapter

Hope, it help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either start the activity when user press on Save, and it will fix it for you.
Or if you want to press back:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(getBooks());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```